# Android progressdialog thread exception

Tags: android, calllog

My app uses the CallLog to collect data and put it into a listview. As this takes time, I tried to use progressdialog to show the user the status of the loading. Unfortunately (I have used progressdialog before) eclipse throws me an error: ***ERROR/AndroidRuntime(771): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.***

```
    public class Calls extends Activity {
    //declaring variables
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.calls);

                lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

                pd = new ProgressDialog(Calls.this);
                pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                pd.setMessage("Loading contacts");
                pd.show();

                //Thread thread = new Thread() {  
                //public void run() {
                Calls.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

        //collecting data from CallLog, putting data into an array
    //Here comes the hard part, which is the root of the problem:


        final ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
             SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();

            for (int b=0; b<storage.length; b++)
            {
                for (int e=0; e<storage[b].length; e++)
                {
                    if (e+3 < storage[b].length)
                    {
                        arr_split_all.add(storage[b][e] + " " + storage[b][e+1] + " " + storage[b][e+2] + " " + storage[b][e+3]);
                        sr1 = new SearchResults();
                        sr1.setData1(storage[b][e+2]);
                        sr1.setData2(storage[b][e]);
                        sr1.setData3(storage[b][e+1]);
                        sr1.setData4(storage[b][e+3]);
                        sr1.setBitmap2(bitmaparray[b]);  //bitmaparray has the same size as storage, and there is no problem with this
                        results.add(sr1);
                    }
                }
            }


            lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(Calls.this, results));  //problematic row
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
           };
           thread.start();
          }
    }//end of onCreate       

   private Handler handler = new Handler() {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            pd.dismiss();
      }
  });    //ADDED a )


     }//end of class 
    //    SearchResults is another class:

            public class SearchResults extends Application{
             private String data1 = "";
             private String data2 = "";
             private String data3 = "";
             private String data4 = "";
             private String bitmap = "";
             private Bitmap bitmap2;


             public void setData1(String data1) {
              this.data1 = data1;
             }

             public String getData1() {
              return data1;
             }

            //etc...
            }
```

And I am using a BaseAdapter class to put the data into the appropriate places of the listview (which consists of an imageview and four textviews), but I don't think that is relevant now.

According to Logcat, the problem is with the            `lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(Calls.this, results));` row. If I attach an arraylist to the listview, it is working fine. Without the progressdialog all textviews and the imageview of each row of the listview is loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `findViewById()` call to your `ListView01` (and later on, the `setAdapter()` call). You cannot modify (or access) views from a custom thread. This has to be done on the UI thread, either via `runOnUiThread()` or in a place where the UI thread runs.